# StatsD Influxdb Insert matching data only

Tags: influxdb

I use the below StatsD config to insert data into Influxdb. But i only want to insert a subset of data based on a match. So what is the key that i can use to specify this that says - insert only if you see this?

```
[influxdb]
host = server1.jot.tre
port = 8086
database = my_db
username = admin
password = admin
prefix = cpu
timeout = 10
precision = "s"
```

So data should be inserted only if it matches with that value specified here. So what is the name of the parameter that i can use.

Answer (score 0):

[Telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/statsd) has a statsd plugin that allows you to define filtering rules for data from statsd and then write that data into InfluxDB.